# creating a new record including a value previously stored and retrieved from cache MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am novice trying to grasp the skill in creating asp.net mvc3 c# with visual studio 2010. I am now looking into membership management and using the default membership provider.  I have extra fields which i have decided to store in a new table and link with the membership unique key.  I am able to retrieve this value and store in cache.  Now I am at a miss as to how to make the unique Id be part of the form collection and save in database.  I have got the create view done using scaffolding and razor. I have created a helper for the caching which can be invoked when and where required

```
Helpers objHelper = new Helpers();
Guid UserID = objHelper.GetCachedUserID(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

Any help detailed enough for a novice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you're looking for :

```
Membership.GetUser("username").ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

However, it looks like you've taken very non standard way of doing things. What do you mean by saying that you store value in cache ?

Additionally, if you're looking for a way to store extra information about each user - there is a Profile provider mechanism that enables you to do so. Check the information at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

Answering your question from the comment below :

If the Unique UserKey is already part of your db model then you can do it this way :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PJCountry PJCountry)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {   
            // adds current user's key
            PJcountry.YourUserKey = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
            db.PJCountries.Add(PJcountry); 
            db.SaveChanges(); 
            return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
        } 
        return View(PJCountry);
    }
```

If you didn't make the changes on DB / model side yet, you will need to shed more light on what paradigm you've chosen - DB first or code first so I could help you out

Comment: Thanks Torm, I was contemplating between storing the unique key of a user from the membership provider in session at user login and storing it in the cache. To be retrieved and used as foreign keys in other tables. I adopted the cache storage which has been implemented with a helper. I need help on how to add unique key on  creating a new record with generated code like `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Create(PJCountry PJCountry){if (ModelState.IsValid){db.PJCountries.Add(PJcountry);   db.SaveChanges(); return RedirectToAction("Index");}return View(PJCountry);}`